# Angular testing with jest : NG0203: `inject()` must be called from an injection context such as a constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, jestjs

I'm testing my angular project with Jest, since the team is using the same tool across many other projects.
I'm trying to test a service, but i cannot instanciate it, and i don't know why. Probably i'm a newbie but i saw many tutorials online and they are always coded like this one.
I cannot explain myself why this code, triggers the famous NG0203 error:

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ENVIRONMENT } from '../core';


describe('UserService', () => {
  let service: UserService;

  beforeEach(async() => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [UserService,
            { provide: ENVIRONMENT,useValue: {
                apiUrl: '/api/',
                jwtTokenName: 'my.token',
              } }
        ]}).compileComponents();
    service = TestBed.inject(UserService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

this is the UserService

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService
{
    private _user: ReplaySubject<User> = new ReplaySubject<User>(1);

    constructor(
      private _apiService: ApiService,
      private _socketService: SocketService,
    ) {
      this._socketService.emitter.subscribe((event: SocketEvent) => { this.onSocketEvent(event); });
    }
}
```

The test output is:

```
 FAIL  src/app/core/user/user.service.spec.ts
  ● UserService › should be created

    NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `EnvironmentInjector#runInContext`. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0203
```

I have a suspect that this isnt about the code but something is messed up elsewhere, like linking deps etc..
Anyone experienced this?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you share your UserService with us ?

Comment: npm link seems to be responsable for some of the problems